# How do I set a value of an a variable in an object Object from another class in the main class using the scanner class (java)

Tags: java

So yeah I am teaching my self java and have been doing so for around a month.
OK i want to call the **name** variable from a class i made and set its value us the **Scanner** class in the **Main method** .

this is what i typed to for this question.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Identification ID = new Identification();

    System.out.println("Enter Full Name");
    ID.setName(name) = scan.next();

    }
 }
```

as I said I'm teaching myself java so could you give me in details

Comment: `ID.setName(scan.next());`?

Comment: OMG it worked still I dont know how i couldnt get that

Comment: By the way, use camel case for your variables. Variables generally start with lower case.

Comment: I thought i did..the String variable **name** is just one work but i understand i yeah i'm practicing that :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
id.setName(scan.nextLine());
```

which is actually passing the string you get with the scanner as parameter into the setter for name member in the identification class..

Comment: OMG it worked still I dont know how i couldnt get that. 
so what you are saying i'm passing the scanner into the setter as its parameter? omg thank you >^_^<